# If two categories are equivalent and the one is monoidal, is the other monoidal too?

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories

Pretty much what I ask in the title.

Let $\mathcal{C},\mathcal{D}$ be two categories and suppose there exists a fully faithful, surjective-on-objects functor $F:\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{D}$ (so that $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$ are equivalent as categories). Suppose further that there is a monoidal category structure on $\mathcal{C}$. Is $\mathcal{D}$ monoidal too?

Comment: Being monoidal is a structure, not a property. What's true is that monoidal structures transport across equivalences of categories. (This is not obvious, and in particular not true of strict monoidal structures.)

Comment: So, are you saying that if $\otimes$ produces a monoidal structure on $\mathcal{C}$ then (something that can be called) $F(\otimes)$ produces a monoidal structure on $\mathcal{D}$?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: That's exactly it. Take a functor $G : \mathcal D → \mathcal C$ such that $F$ and $G$ form an adjoint equivalence, and you will see that there is a natural way to transport every piece of monoidal structure from $\mathcal C$ to $\mathcal D$. Checking that the coherence axioms are satisfied will then be a lengthy but routine calculation.